# Can I use two separate browser-language-based RewriteCond's in .htaccess for root and subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Can I use two separate browser-language-based RewriteCond's in .htaccess? One is for the domain root, one is for the subdomain 'm'.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_cz.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /m/index_cz.html [L,R=301]
```

At the moment the first rule works fine, but the second rule does not appear to function and instead is showing the root index_cz.php if language 'cs' is found. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_cz.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /m/index_cz.html [L,R=301]
```

your conditions are same! how apache should detect the difference!
If you want to use different languages, so change the conditions!

**Edit**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index_cz.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/index_cz.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: They are the same because one is to apply the condition to the root and one is to apply the condition to the subdomain 'm.mydomain.com' (which uses folder /m/ for its content).

Comment: @JoeW ,ok I added host name to condition! but you said you want to different languages !!!Did I misundertand?

Comment: I will explain myself a little better. First we have a rewrite rule that detects if the user's browser is in Czech or English. This sends them to either index_cz.php (Czech) or index.php (English). However, we also have javasript that detects then if the user's browser is on a mobile device. If it is, the user us sent to the subdomain 'm.domain.com' and if not, they are sent to index.php of the root as usual. However, we have two mobile versions in m.domain.com... index_cz.html (Czech) and index.html (English). It's complicated, I hope I have explained it better this time!

Comment: Hmmmm... maybe I should put a separate .htaccess in the subdomain folder.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are parsed one after the other. Because of the 'L' instruction, as soon as a condition is fulfilled, the other rules are not checked, if my memory is good. This means you would have to add something to differentiate your conditions. When do you want each of the rewrite rules applied? Does 'm' stand for mobile? You are talking about a subdomain... You should then check for the subdomain too in the conditions.

If you really have an 'm' subdomain, what you mant might be the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} m.YourDomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /m/index_cz.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.YourDomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_cz.php [L,R=301]
```

Don' forget to replace YourDomain.com by your actual domain name.

Does this help?

Comment: The first condition does not work for the subdomain unfortunately. The second condition works as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot some characters in the domain checking. I should have written:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.YourDomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /m/index_cz.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.YourDomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_cz.php [L,R=301]
```

I escaped the periods in the domain name and added a ^ at the beginning of the mobile subdomain. That sign means "starts with".

And you will need two extra sets of rules for English too.